# Counting neighbors with wrap around in 2d array(game of life)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life, neighbours

So I'm trying to build the game of life program and I am fairly fresh to java/coding in general and I am having issues wrapping my head around wrap around in 2D arrays. I have a constructor and methods that will build me an array and place "cells" where I want them but I dont understand how I can see how many neighbors a cell has.

To sum it up:

I can make a 2D array of whatever type.

I can place "cells" at different elements in the array

Now how do I see is the spaces next to my cell being checked has neighbors on all side( I use a nested for loop to go through each cell)?

KEEP IN MIND! Wrap around is in effect here.

UPDATE: This is what I have but when I test it it returns 1 less neighbor than there should be. 
UPDATE 2: I removed the first if statement because I don't think it makes sense with it. But now I cant get c to go up 1.

```
public int neighborCount(int row, int col) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < society.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < society[0].length; c++) {
                // up and left
                if ((society[(r - 1 + row) % row][(c - 1 + col) %    col]) == cell) {
                    count++;
                }
                // up
                if ((society[(r - 1 + row) % row][c]) == cell) {
                    count++;
                }
                // up and right
                if ((society[(r - 1 + row) % row][(c + 1 + col) % col]) == cell) {
                    count++;
                }
                // left
                if ((society[r][(c - 1 + col) % col]) == cell) {
                    count++;
                }
                // right
                if ((society[r][(c + 1 + col) % col]) == cell) {
                    count++;
                }
                // down and left
                if ((society[(r + 1 + row) % row][(c - 1 + col) % col]) == cell) {
                    count++;
                }
                // down
                if ((society[(r + 1 + row) % row][c]) == cell) {
                    count++;
                }
                // down and right
                if ((society[(r + 1 + row) % row][(c + 1 + col) % col]) == cell) {
                    count++;
                }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

My test:

```
@Test
public void testNeighborsWrapping() {
    GameOfLife society = new GameOfLife(10, 16);
    society.growCellAt(3, 3);
    society.growCellAt(3, 4);
    society.growCellAt(3, 5);
    assertEquals(0, society.neighborCount(2, 1));
    assertEquals(1, society.neighborCount(2, 2));
    assertEquals(2, society.neighborCount(2, 3));
    assertEquals(3, society.neighborCount(2, 4));

}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you just check each cell manually?

Comment: Well id like to have my method do it for me so I can just say go and it goes.

Comment: In your method you check each (surrounding) cell manually.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm asking is how do I account for wrap around? Like if I have a cell in the [0][0] spot how do I get that to count the neighbors that will be in the bottom right corner of my grid because of wrap around?

Comment: use a few if statements.

Comment: Could you put me on the right path? I have no idea how to account for those wrap around values. Its not connecting in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, the code could be something like

```
Object[] getNeighbors(int i, int j) {
    // put code to return the neighbors given an index
}

boolean allNeighborsFull(int i, int j) {
    Object[] neighbors = getNeighbors(i, j);
    boolean allFull = true;
    for (Object neighbor : neighbors) {
        if (!neighbor.full()) {
            allFull = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return allFull;
}

boolean allNeighborsSurrounded() {
    Object[] neighbors = getNeighbors(i, j);
    // check each one of these using the method above
}
```

Comment: Oh, just that part. Well, one simple way is to hard-code the neighbors. Just check that if you are accessing i-1, then i > 0. If you are accessing i+1, then i < length - 1. There are just 8 neighbors.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow really

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
public Cell[] getNeighbours(int i, int j) {
    int i2 = i - 1;
    int i3 = i + 1;
    int j2 = j - 1;
    int j3 = j + 1;
    if (i2 == -1)
        i2 = board.length - 1;
    if (i3 == board.length)
        i3 = 0;
    if (j2 == -1)
        j2 = board[i].length - 1;
    if (j3 == board[i].length)
        j3 = 0;
    return new Cell[] {
        board[i2][j2], board[i2][j], board[i2][j3],
        board[i][j2], board[i][j3], board[i3][j2],
        board[i3][j], board[i3][j3]
    };
}
```